# How to create a custom environment with a listing inside it?

Tags: macros, listings, environments

Well consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4, oneside,openleft]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\begin{flushright}\begin{minipage}{0.9\textwidth}\begin{lstlisting}
for (i) {
    hello world i;
}
\end{lstlisting}\end{minipage}\end{flushright}
\end{document}
```

Now I wish to have this as a single environment "codebox". So I tried (the simplified):

```
\documentclass[a4, oneside,openleft]{book}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{codebox}{\begin{flushright}}{\end{flushright}}

\begin{document}
\begin{codebox}
for (i) {
    hello world i;
}
\end{codebox}
\end{document}
```

However this returns the following error:

> Overfull \hbox (3190.24414pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 59--61
>   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][
>   ][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
>   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][
>   ][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]
>   [][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][
>   ][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][][]  )

So how to fix this?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @Jubobs The question is NOT answered. I find it quite arrogant to see such a comment, assuming I don't know what to do. Especially as I said in the comments to the answerer that the solution doesn't provide me with everything I need.

Comment: For information, my earlier comment is one of the [stock comments](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks) listed on the meta site; it wasn't meant to be arrogant, but simply to encourage you to accept the answer you got, *if it solved your problem*. I thought it did; my mistake.

Answer (score 5):

`listings` way of defining new code environments is

```
\lstnewenvironment{codebox}
   {\lstset{language = C,linewidth=0.9\linewidth}}
   {}
```

Where you specify your language. To flush right as in your first code, you can use `xleftmargin` in `\lstset`

```
\documentclass[a4, oneside,openleft]{book}
\usepackage{showframe}  %% just for demo
\usepackage{listings}
\lstnewenvironment{codebox}
  {\lstset{language = C,linewidth=0.9\linewidth,xleftmargin=0.1\linewidth}}
  {}

\begin{document}
\begin{codebox}
for (i) {
    hello world i;
}
\end{codebox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wish to do some formatting (ie flushright) that can't be done through lstset...

Comment: @paul23 As in your first code? You can use `xleftmargin`. See the update.

Comment: that indeed works for this case - but for the generic case where I wish to create a combined environment with minipage etc?

Comment: @paul23 Why do you want a `minipage` inside a listing?

Comment: No I wish to create a listing inside a minipage/whatever.

Comment: @paul23 Could you elaborate on how Harish's answer isn't satisfactory? That would help others find a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your second snippet isn't really the overfull box (which is a warning, not an error), but the fact that using a `flushright` environment in

```
\lstnewenvironment{codebox}
  {\begin{flushright}}
  {\end{flushright}}
```

causes LaTeX to raise a `(job aborted, no legal \end found)` error. You could remedy that error by using a `\raggedleft` instead of a `flushright` environment, like so:

```
\lstnewenvironment{codebox}
  {\raggedleft}
  {}
```

but that still wouldn't affect the vertical alignment of your listing. For a workaround, see below.

By the way, `a4` and `openleft` are not valid options for `book`. Did you mean `a4paper` and `openany`, instead?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, oneside, openany]{book}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\lstnewenvironment{codebox}{%
  \lstset{frame=single}%
  \vspace{\baselineskip}
  \hfill%
  \minipage{.9\textwidth}%
}{%
  \endminipage%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codebox}
for (i) {
    hello world i;
}
\end{codebox}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Again, correct me if I understood it wrongly: but this puts the a minipage INSIDE the codebox (which would then fill the whole page width). I am afraid this would lead to problems when say I wish to add a background to the codebox.

Comment: @paul23 This approach puts your listing in a `minipage`. I don't anticipate any problem related to background colour. Try it for yourself and see.